# Build a IIS and SQL Server replicated cluster

Tags: sql-server, replication, windows, windows-server-2012-r2, mirroring

I have four Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard virtual machines on three physical nodes. Two will be dedicated for IIS, and two for SQL Server 2014 Standard.

I have to replicate them (IIS1 to IIS2 and SQL1 to SQL2) to have an high availability system.

I already have a load balancing/failover system, because I can have this services on the perimetral firewalls, and if it possible I would like that every nodes have local storage replicated to/from the other node, so if it possible I wouldn't use a shared storage like SAN.

What configuration do you advise to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iis hosting you can use shared configuration : 
http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/managing-your-configuration-settings/shared-configuration_264#02

For site content you must use "staging" and production concept .

One server is "staging" and you push your site with webdploy from a local iis on your laptop to this staging server for exemple . And from staging to prod when staging is ok :)

Some script to add but easy .

For sql2012 if you want easy to do "high availibility" you must use sql always on FCI( fail over cluster) :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189134.aspx

But and old solution for sql replication is just use sql logshipping for replication easy to use and low prerequire .

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187103.aspx

And you could backup from this logshiping target server without loading "prod" database.

For small scale deploy webdpoy ,shared config ,sql logshiping is a robust solution .

Answer (score 1):

Hyper-V on 2012 and 2012 R2 has built-in replication of virtual machines. Just enable it and replicate the VM's.

Comment: I cannot do that because I'm not using Hyper-V and I cannot replicate virtual machine. Cannot I replicate from node to node?

Comment: @Mat Well, for SQL you could use AlwaysOn (SQL Enterprise License required), mirroring, log shipping, replication. Do you really need to keep IIS replicated? Can't you just deploy the web application to both servers when you release new updates?

Comment: Are you referring to "Alwayson Failover Cluster Instances"? I see that for 2 nodes it's available on SQL Server 2014 Standard, isn't it? Will mirroring or replication work both sides? Will both nodes be active? Yes for IIS, I think I could deploy two times.

Comment: @Mat No, FCI is for shared storage clusters. AlwaysOn can use a clustered SQL instance and provide AlwaysOn replication to another cluster or host (like a remote site). It still requires a enteprise license.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. I have a standard license for SQL Server. What is the best I can use so?

Comment: @Mat I wrote several options for you in the first comment reply. Please read it.